# Knockout.js options binding - deselecting option when option has been removed

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a dropdown (select control) bound to an observable array using the options, optionsValue, optionsText, and optionsCaption bindings.

If I have an option selected and then later remove it, the dropdown selects the first item.  I would like it to set the selected value to undefined without having to add an empty item to the observable array.

Here is a simple example:

```
<select data-bind="value: selectedItemValue, options: items, optionsValue: 'value', optionsText: 'text', optionsCaption: ''"></select>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: selectLast">Select Last</button>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: removeLastItem">Remove Last</button>

var viewmodel = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.items = ko.observableArray();
    this.selectedItemValue = ko.observable(null);

    this.selectLast = function () {
        self.selectedItemValue(
        self.items()[self.items().length - 1].value);
    };

    this.removeLastItem = function () {
        self.items.pop();
    };
    this.items.push({
        value: "item1",
        text: "First item"
    });
    this.items.push({
        value: "item2",
        text: "Second item"
    });
    this.items.push({
        value: "item3",
        text: "Third item"
    });
};

var vm = new viewmodel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guvbxor2/)

1. Click the Select Last button or manually select the last item in the drop down
2. Click the Remove Last button
3. Result: First item gets selected

What is the best approach to achieve the behavior I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the introduction of the `valueAllowUnset` in the pull request:

[#647](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/647) - add option that allows the value binding to accept a selected value that is not currently in the list of options

This old bug/feature has been fixed. So if you upgrade your fiddle to use at least **KO version 3.1** it is working as you described:

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nn0osq9t/)

Comment: Thanks, for some reason that didn't show up in my search results.  Just to further elaborate for others:

Simply upgrading to 3.1 will achieve the behavior I want (deselect and set value to null).

Setting valueAllowUnset to true will deselect and leave value unchanged even though no matching values are in the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what nemesv mentions you can simply remove the value if the last one is matching the current selected value -

```
this.removeLastItem = function () {
    var lastItem = self.items()[self.items().length - 1];
    if (self.selectedItemValue() === lastItem.value) {
        self.selectedItemValue(null);
    }
    self.items.pop();
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/guvbxor2/4/

Basically just check if you are about to remove the option that is selected and if so `null` it